# Vectorize this for loop in numpy

Tags: numpy

I am trying to compute matrix z (defined below) in python with numpy.

[image]

Here's my current solution (using 1 for loop)

```
z = np.zeros((n, k))
for i in range(n):
    v = pi * (1 / math.factorial(x[i])) * np.exp(-1 * lamb) * (lamb ** x[i])
    numerator = np.sum(v)
    c = v / numerator
    z[i, :] = c
return z
```

Is it possible to completely vectorize this computation? I need to do this computation for thousands of iterations, and matrix operations in numpy is much faster than huge for loops.

Comment: Add a minimal sample case?

Comment: @Divakar thanks for commenting. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/hkalexling/8b97806017cb7cd4ad4937ec1deb157b) can be used as a example (python3). An EM algorithm is implemented, and I would like to vectorize the `E(x)` function.

Comment: Is `lamb` constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized version of `E`. It replaces the `for-loop` and scalar arithmetic with [NumPy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and array-based arithmetic:

```
def alt_E(x):
    x = x[:, None]
    z = pi * (np.exp(-lamb) * (lamb**x)) / special.factorial(x)
    denom = z.sum(axis=1)[:, None]
    z /= denom
    return z
```

---

I ran [em.py](https://gist.github.com/hkalexling/8b97806017cb7cd4ad4937ec1deb157b) to get a sense for the typical size of `x`, `lamb`, `pi`, `n` and `k`. On data of this size,
`alt_E` is about 120x faster than `E`:

```
In [32]: %timeit E(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit alt_E(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.7 µs per loop

In [34]: 11500/94.7
Out[34]: 121.43611404435057
```

---

This is the setup I used for the benchmark:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as special

def alt_E(x):
    x = x[:, None]
    z = pi * (np.exp(-lamb) * (lamb**x)) / special.factorial(x)
    denom = z.sum(axis=1)[:, None]
    z /= denom
    return z


def E(x):
    z = np.zeros((n, k))
    for i in range(n):
        v = pi * (1 / math.factorial(x[i])) * \
            np.exp(-1 * lamb) * (lamb ** x[i])
        numerator = np.sum(v)
        c = v / numerator
        z[i, :] = c
    return z

n = 576
k = 2

x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5])

lamb = np.array([ 0.84835141, 1.04025989])
pi = np.array([ 0.5806958, 0.4193042])

assert np.allclose(alt_E(x), E(x))
```

---

By the way, `E` could also be calculated using [`scipy.stats.poisson`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html#scipy-stats-poisson):

```
import scipy.stats as stats
pois = stats.poisson(mu=lamb)

def alt_E2(x):
    z = pi * pois.pmf(x[:,None])
    denom = z.sum(axis=1)[:, None]
    z /= denom
    return z
```

but this does not turn out to be faster, at least for arrays of this length:

```
In [33]: %timeit alt_E(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.7 µs per loop

In [102]: %timeit alt_E2(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 278 µs per loop
```

For larger `x`, `alt_E2` is faster:

```
In [104]: x = np.random.random(10000)

In [106]: %timeit alt_E(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.18 ms per loop

In [105]: %timeit alt_E2(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 643 µs per loop
```

Comment: You are the real MVP ;)